# Brown spots on mango leaves

Tags: houseplants, pest-damage

I germinated and then planted a mango from the pit of a store-bought fruit. It has been kept indoors by a window, and was just repotted 2 days ago in “cactus/citrus” soil.

Over the last week, I noticed that brown spots on the leaves started appearing, getting darker. They are not raised, and seem to start from the top of the leaf, not the bottom. About a week ago I also felt a bit of sticky residue under the leaves and cleaned it. I looked intently and could not find any bugs like mites or mealy bugs.

[image]

---

Hopefully this is clearer. I checked the back with a magnifying glass and there is nothing there. I am mystified!

[image]

---

This is the back of the leaf, spots are much lighter.
[image]

Comment: The photo does not magnify well so its not possible to see the brown spots and streaks clearly, unfortunately - can you upload a better one, maybe a higher resolution one? From the blurred image I can see, it looks like the brown areas are along veins in the leaf - check the back of the leaf with a magnifying glass because whatever's on it may be tiny and the same colour as the leaf - in particular, check along the veins on the back

Comment: Please be sure to use the [edit] link underneath your question if you want to update it with new information. Thanks and welcome to the site!